# Looping backwards through data values

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am guessing my logic does not work do to the values I am using in the loop.  Not quite sure how to proceed.  Thank you.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var ash = ss.getSheetByname("Master List C");
var laRow = ash.getLastRow();
var laCol = ash.getLastColumn();
var toMove = [];

var dsh = ss.getSheetByname("Non-Members");
var ldRow = dsh.getLastRow();
var ldCol = dsh.getLastColumn();

var range = ash.getRange(9, 1, laRow, laCol);
var aData = range.getValues();

for (row = aData.length; row >= 9; row--) {
   if (aData[row][6] == "No") {
     var tmp = [aData[row][0], aData[row][1], aData[row][2], aData[row][3], aData[row][4], aData[row][5], aData[row][8]];
     toMove.push(tmp);
     dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, toMove.length, 7).setValues(toMove);
     ash.deleteRow(row);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Where's the description of what is not working with your current code?

Comment: When it executes, it does not move any of the rows that are flagged.  I loop from the bottom up as I know I should, but I am not sure if the for/next logic is correct.  Is there something I am doing wrong in the loop itself?  Thanks

Comment: You should specify how you execute this function, and report any errors it gives (this and your previous comment are important enough to have in your question, not comments). You should probably move the write step outside of the loop.

Comment: Cannot read property "6" from undefined.

Comment: Also your counter "row" is incorrect.  You got data starting with row 9 so aData.length is laRow-8 so ash.delete(row) will be off by 8

Comment: @James  error messages (in **full**, including line number) belong *in the question itself* When you present only an excerpt of your code, you should mark the line in your presented code that throws the error.

Comment: Got it.  Worked through the errors one by one.  Some stupid mistakes on my part.  That you for your help.